# Dependencies between Sonata's Bundles

Tags: php, symfony, dependencies, composer-php, sonata

I have created a Symfony application and added in my composer.json:

- sonata-project/admin-bundle
- sonata-project/formatter-bundle
- sonata-project/intl-bundle
- sonata-project/media-bundle
- sonata-project/classification-bundle
- sonata-project/user-bundle

When I used

> composer install

All worked fine. But when I want to update I have too many dependencies error, for example, user-bundle need admin-bundle 2.x-dev and classification-bundle need admin-bundle 3.0.0. I tried different (included dev-master) for each sonata bundle.

Someone can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

My composer.json:

```
{
"name": "navalex/.checkout",
"license": "proprietary",
"type": "project",
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "app/AppKernel.php",
        "app/AppCache.php"
    ]
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",

    "ornicar/gravatar-bundle": "^1.1",
    "coresphere/console-bundle": "dev-master",
    "whiteoctober/breadcrumbs-bundle": "^1.2",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.2",

    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "3.0.0",
    "sonata-project/block-bundle": "3.0.0",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "3.0.0",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "^2.1",
    "sonata-project/formatter-bundle": "^2.3",
    "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "^2.2",
    "sonata-project/media-bundle": "^2.3",
    "sonata-project/classification-bundle": "^2.2",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "^2.2"
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~3.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~2.7"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin",
    "platform": {
        "php": "5.5"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste the versions you are requiring?

The issue will be probably solved if you require more permissive versions. For example, if you require them all to `v3.0.0`, maybe you will have errors if the library's tag policy is poorly designed. However, if you use `*`then composer will probably find a version that will fit all the crossed requirements.